Quantlib - Clarification on iborStartDate in FuturesRateHelper
I'm currently working with QuantLib's FuturesRateHelper and I'm a bit confused about the iborStartDate parameter. According to the documentation and some code snippets, iborStartDate is used like this:

From the example, it's not entirely clear what iborStartDate refers to specifically. Does it correspond to the expiration date of the futures contract, or is it related to something else?

I have looked on Refinitiv, but couldn't find additional information that clarifies this point. Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated!

An IBOR fixing (for instance, a fixing for the 3-months Euribor) is an interest rate corresponding to an underlying period determined by various index conventions.  For instance, the Euribor 3M fixing for today, Friday, November 8th 2024, is the interest rate for a period starting two business days from today (Tuesday 12th) and ending three months later (February 12th, 2025).
The futures is based on such a fixing at a future date.  The iborStartDate is the start of the underlying period.

Upon examining the C++ code, we observe the following implementation for the FuturesRateHelper constructor:
    FuturesRateHelper::FuturesRateHelper(const Handle<Quote>& price,
                                         const Date& iborStartDate,
                                         Natural lengthInMonths,
                                         const Calendar& calendar,
                                         BusinessDayConvention convention,
                                         bool endOfMonth,
                                         const DayCounter& dayCounter,
                                         Handle<Quote> convAdj,
                                         Futures::Type type)
    : RateHelper(price), convAdj_(std::move(convAdj)) {
        CheckDate(iborStartDate, type);
 
        earliestDate_ = iborStartDate;
        maturityDate_ =
            calendar.advance(iborStartDate, lengthInMonths * Months, convention, endOfMonth);
        yearFraction_ = DetermineYearFraction(earliestDate_, maturityDate_, dayCounter);
        // Sets the pillar date for the term structure
        pillarDate_ = latestDate_ = latestRelevantDate_ = maturityDate_;
 
        registerWith(convAdj_);
    }

In this code, the variable iborStartDate determines the start date of the contract, consequently impacting its maturity date as seen in
calendar.advance(iborStartDate, lengthInMonths * Months, convention, endOfMonth);

Which will calculate the maturity starting from iborStartDate. Meaning it is a forward starting contract. This can be observed in the following example:
import QuantLib as ql
import datetime

ref_date = ql.Date.from_date(datetime.date(2024, 1, 1))
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ref_date
ibor_start_date = ql.Date().from_date(datetime.date(2024, 3, 20))
future_helper = ql.FuturesRateHelper(100, ibor_start_date, ql.Euribor3M())
print(future_helper.pillarDate())

Running this Python code will display the maturity date of the futures contract, which in this case will be 2024-06-20, three months after the IBOR start date of 2024-03-20.
